# How I could execute this code in Pycharm? Python code with parameters

Tags: python, pycharm

Maybe you know *Pycharm*, it is a piece of software for python programming. I am at level 1 in programming. So, I have a project in mind, it is with Manim, a software of ***Grant Sanderson*** of ***1blue3brown*** youtube channel.

Well, this is the problem. For execute the project, the manim piece for render the video, it is:

`C:\manim> python -m manim file_with_my_project_scenes.py scene -pl`

this code is, for rendering the **animation video**.

So I wanna work in *pycharm*, because i want to learn more about. But I don´t know how to run it with these **parameters** or if it is possible even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in pycharm like this:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class Example_Scene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dot = Dot()
        self.add(dot)
        self.wait(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    module_name = os.path.basename(__file__)
    command_A = "manim -p  -s -c  --video_dir ~/Downloads/  "
    command_B = module_name +" " +"Example_Scene"
    os.system(command_A + command_B)
```

Example_Scene is an easy minimal Scene.
command_A gives you all the options, like -p for preview, -l for low quality, etc...
and command_B looks for your file and for your scene.
Good luck!